# Can jvm be configured to be considerate and share computing resources (CPU and RAM) with other processes?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, cpu-usage, single-threaded

I am running existing programs written in Java or Scala. These programs are written by different authors and serve very different purposes, so integrating them into one mega-program is not feasible. When any of these java programs are launched on a node with many cores (e.g. 32) and much RAM (e.g. 200G), each try to take as much resource as possible, to the extent that the node slows to a halt and no useful computation gets done. For example, running 32 instances of [Beagle](https://faculty.washington.edu/browning/beagle/beagle.html) on different datasets leads to 32 jvms that each try to use 32 cores and most of the memory. (Beagle is not configured for explicit multithreading with `nthreads=1` as the default.)

So how can I configure jvm to behave more like a traditional program that only uses as much memory and CPU as it really needs...

I am aware of the following flags, but are there any other flags to consider?

`-Xmx               limits maximum memory
-XX:+UseSerialGC   disables multithreaded garbage collection`

Can the jvm truly be single-threaded?

Additionally, fairly light-weight java programs all try to use at least 30G of RAM on a node with 200G of RAM, when they really only need <1G of RAM. I set `-Xmx1G` and these programs ran without error or noticeable performance degradation; in fact, the start-up time was much quicker.

Is there a more elegant solution than setting a hard upper limit on memory? If I set `-Xmx` too low, the program crashes. If I set it too high, resources are wasted. Working with programs written in C++ written by careful authors, I don't need to tweak these things. The C++ program memory usage usually scales predictably with input data size.

Why can't jvm use as much as it actually needs by default?

Aside from `nice` and `ulimit`, are there better solutions?

`nice +10 java` can run into trouble when new processes are continuously being launched with higher priority.
`ulimit java` can cause jvm to throw fits.

I am working in an environment with no root access. I am not working on a Linux server and not on Android.

Comment: I don't know but android already share RAM between processes, I don't know if this is related but it could be :)

Comment: You can control Beagle using its command line options (nthreads). Surprise: Reading the docs of a software you use helps.

Comment: @Durandal Beagle's `nthread` default is 1 so it should run in single-thread by default. In fact, the version of Beagle I used did not support multithreading. I contacted the author about Beagle taking over all the cores, and he maintains the version of Beagle I used was strictly single-threaded. Importantly, I only used Beagle as an example. Other programs can also have >100% CPU usage, likely due to multithreaded garbage collection. Part of the question is whether jvm will multithread during other tasks and how to disable it.

Comment: It only uses as much memory and CPU as it needs already. Using `-Xmx` only set the maximum memory it will use before dying with an OOME.

Answer (score 1):

> `-XX:-UseSerialGC`

that *disables* serial GC, which is the opposite of what you want.

> I am working in an environment with no root access.

If the kernel is compiled with user namespaces you can use `unshare` to enter a new user namespace and then use *cgroups* within that namespace to limit resources.

Comment: According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html, `-XX:-UseSerialGC` uses serial garbage collection.

Comment: The `cgroups` option is interesting (though I am pretty sure we use a stock kernel). Is it practically different from `ulimit`?

Comment: the table just describes the options, whether the option is turned on and off is determined by the +/-. it's mentioned in the prose above the table: *"Boolean options are turned on with -XX:+<option> and turned off with -XX:-<option>."*

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the table.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the jvm truly be single-threaded?

No, when it can run concurrently it does.  You can use taskset to limit the JCVM to just one CPU byte it will perform quite badly if you do this, as it does need more than one CPU.

> Is there a more elegant solution than setting a hard upper limit on memory?

I would try to determine what you mean by that.

> Why can't jvm use as much as it actually needs?

It does use as much CPU and memory as it needs.

> nice +10 java can run into trouble when new processes are continuously being launched

Launching new JVMs can create far more overhead than benefit. I would start JVMs as little as possible if you want to save CPU.